# Asking other players for materials in Simcity Buildit

Tags: simcity-buildit

I recently started playing Simcity Buildit.  I need materials and can't find them just by going to other players' cities and checking the Global Trade HQ. How can I ask other players for items I need?  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

You can’t ask players for what they need unless you have the mayor's club (unlocked at level 18). Then you can either make a club or join an existing club. You can then send messages to club memebers and ask for items. You can find more information on [EA’s Help Pages.](https://help.ea.com/en-gb/help/simcity/simcity-buildit/simcity-buildit-mayors-club/.)